# How to create carousel items with splice based on item count using React-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-carousel

I am trying to do splice, so that each page (Active & Other items) displays 3 items. But this is not working. Can someone help here please?

Below is the code:

```
var Cards1= filter.splice(0, Math.ceil(filter.length / 3)).map( item => {
  return (
    <div class="cards">
    <div class="title">
    <h6><b>{item.Name }</b></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="des">
    <p> {item.DescriptionEN}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
})
var Cards2= filter.splice(filter.length / 3).map( item => {
  return (
    <div class="cards">
    <div class="title">
    <h6><b>{item.Name }</b></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="des">
    <p> {item.DescriptionEN}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
})
<div class="main">
<div id="inam" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<div class="card-deck">
{Cards1}
</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<div class="card-deck">
{Cards2}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How many carousel items do you need? I am not sure if you are going to show 2 or 3 carousel items.

Comment: 3 carousel items in each page

Comment: My about code doesnt work for 3 items. I would really appreciate any help here . i have tried everything. nothing works

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      filter: [
        {
          name: "AAA",
          description: "BBB"
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  renderCards = (cards) => (
    cards.map(item => (
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="title">
          <h6><b>{item.name}</b></h6>
        </div>
        <div class="des">
          <p>{item.description}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))
  )

  getSeparatedArray = (array) => {
    const res = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 3) {
        const temp = array.slice(i, i + 3);
        res.push(temp);
    }
    return res;
  }

  render () {
    const { filter } = this.state
    const cardsList = this.getSeparatedArray(filter)

    return (
      <div class="main">
        <div id="inam" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            {
              cardsList.map(cards => (
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="card-deck">
                    {this.renderCards(cards)}
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. this really helped me . But only issue is i may not be able to do this if i have 100 items/cards . instead of defining as const cards , is that something which i could do..? I would really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: It doesn't matter even you have more than 100 items. Lemme update the answer so that you can get sth.

Comment: One more thing i would like to add, with the above solution, i am getting 3 items in firstslide and 2 items in subsequent slides.

Comment: Let's say the filter array length is 7. In this case, the current logic will show 2, 2, 3 items.

Comment: I've just edited it again. Hope it is what you need.

Comment: If there's more to add, please lemme know. If not I hope you check the answer for the other guys.

Comment: In my case, current Length shows as  23, so it shows as Array(8), Array(8), Array (7) is the split. but i want the first and subsequent slide to have only 3 items :-(

Comment: Also, in my UI it says ReferenceError: renderCards is not defined, if i access this.renderCards, UI displays nothing

Comment: So do you need sth like Array(3), Array(3), Array(17)?

Comment: You should use `this.renderCards(cards)`. I've edited above code.

Comment: I would need Array(3), Array(3), Array(3) , Array(3) , Array(3), Array(3), Array(3) , Array(2) -> Length is not fixed, so whatever the length would be it should split the array to 3 items. if items are less then 2 or 1 instead of 3.

Comment: I've changed `getSeparatedArray` function. It would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your prompt response. I see now the array split in logs is proper but in UI doesnt show anything :-(

Comment: Edited again. I've tested this on my side and it showed texts. Please check it on your side as well.

Comment: not sure what am i missing here, in logs i see its getting proper array. but in UI Cards, it displays empty instead of separatedArray :-(